# Conversion of numbers from one form (string) to other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame "df" with a column "Amount", which contains values in millions like 2.3, 17, 1.47 and so on. I want to create a new column "Amount1" in "df" which converts each value in "Amount" to the form like 2300000, 17000000, 1470000 and so on. How would I accomplish this task? The below code throws the error - Invalid Syntax.

```
df[Amount1] = df[Amount]
df[Amount1] = df.Amount1 * 1000000
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to write the code. Added my code

Comment: Please also show how that didn't work. What happened? Did you get an unexpected result? Did it raise an error? If so, please add the full error message to your post.

Comment: @ayhan Updated Post.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the full error message. Please always post the full error message when asking questions.

Comment: @ayhan Thats the full error message which I received while running my code. You can follow other comments on this post to see some other error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to `float` first by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Amount1'] = df.Amount.astype(float) * 1000000
```

If it doesnt work, use another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444939/2901002).

Maybe there is some space in values, so remove it by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['Amount1'] = df.Amount.str.strip().astype(float) * 1000000
```

EDIT:

```
df['Amount1'] = df.Amount.str.replace('-','.').astype(float) * 1000000
```

Or:

```
df['Amount1'] = df.Amount.str.replace('-','').astype(float) * 1000000
```

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: So try find problematic rows `df[pd.to_numeric(df.Amount, errors='coerce').isnull()]` - whatis in column `Amount` ?

Comment: Yes there are few rows with "-" value in the Amount. How do we deal with this?

Comment: Héhé, I was faster. @piRSquared

Comment: Still the same error! ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: Can you post values what return `df.ix[pd.to_numeric(df.Amount, errors='coerce').isnull(), 'Amount'].tolist()` ?

Comment: All are same -  u'-',
 u'-',
 u'-',
 u'-',
 u'-',
 u'-',
 u'-',

Comment: So then use another solution `df['Amount1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Amount, errors='coerce') * 1000000` - you get NaN in these problemtic values.

Comment: Yes I get NaN, but then other values are of form 1.597500e+09

Comment: Yes, if in columns is only one `NaN` - `int` are converted to `float` - see [choice-of-na-representation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#choice-of-na-representation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117639/discussion-between-user6461192-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Amount1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Amount, errors='coerce') * 1000000
```

Comment: you supposed let some low rated guys answer this kind of questions. = P

Comment: @piRSquared ValueError: Unable to parse string

Comment: This is harder than we thought it was going to be.

Comment: @AdrienLeber The problem is not always easy as it seems to be :P